# Is it possible generate three public key( address ) by only one private key?

Tags: address, private-key, public-key, address-generation

I hear that each address has one private key.
Is it possible generate three public key address by only one private key?

Comment: You need at least two private keys to get three addresses: you can get one address from each private key (in two formats) plus a 3rd multisig address if you combine the two.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "public key address" ?

From one private key, you can generate:

1. A pay-to-pubkey hash address that uses the uncompressed form of the public key.
2. Pay-to-script hash address, where the script is (1)
3. Pay-to-script hash address, with a  OP_CHECKSIG script
4. Pay-to-script hash addresses, paying to 1-of-1 OP_CHECKMULTISIG with uncompressed pubkey.

And all of the above could use the compressed form of the pubkey to get another 4 addresses.

So one private key can be represented by eight different addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, no. Each private key corresponds to exactly one public key. This public key can be represented in two ways that give different addresses: uncompressed and compressed. This gives you two addresses for a private key.

You could, however, use the private key as a seed to generate more private keys, much like [Electrum's 128-bit seed](https://electrum.org/seed.html). For example, if your seed were the 24-bit 6B8ABC in hex, use the following numbers as private keys

- SHA256(6B8ABC00)
- SHA256(6B8ABC01)
- SHA256(6B8ABC02)

(note: do not use a 24-bit seed or private key, as someone could easily steal your bitcoins)

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2: one address using the public key in compressed form and a second using the public key in uncompressed form.